# How to extract the jsonobject based on timestamp

Tags: java, selenium

I have an logging content API which returns an list of json objects which will have transactions logged details. Say for example if i do GET request, it will log the details in log table and the log API also will return that content along with previously logged content. So if i do GET for 5 times, i would see 5 objects in the log API returned list. But only key for me to extract the latest logged data is 'timestamp' and all other keys in the object will be same. I am not sure how to extract the latest data correctly with 'timestamp'.

```
[
    {
        "type": "SERVICE_CALL",
        "timestamp": "2022-12-14T10:03:01.343Z",
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": "<test>/v5/accounts/123",
        "requestBody": "",
        "requestTime": "",
        "statusCode": 404
    },
    {
        "type": "SERVICE_CALL",
        "timestamp": "2022-12-14T10:03:30.343Z",
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": "<test>/v5/accounts/123",
        "requestBody": "",
        "requestTime": "",
        "statusCode": 404
    }
]
```

In the above example, both the log content is same except 'timestamp' with difference in seconds. I need to grab the latest data from this. How can i get it in JAVA?

Comment: I can imagine creating instances of java Date objects using the timestamp strings, and then comparing them to one another to figure out the most recent request. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Why the selenium tag?

Comment: @JoeChris That terrible `Date` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Comment: If all the data is the same, why would you want the latest?

Comment: @BasilBourque, because i need to know when a GET call (another API) is triggered, it inserts a new entry in log table every time, even though the call is same content. only thing is timestamp is updated with current.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to iterate the `JSONArray` and compare the `timestamp` fields using `java.time.*` APIs. Since all other fields are same, you just need to store the index in the array where the max timestamp was seen. Then you can extract the corresponding `JSONObject` at the end.

```java
JSONArray jsonArr = ...;  // get the JSONArray object from source

int index = -1;
Instant maxTimestamp = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    Instant timestamp = Instant.parse(jsonObj.getString("timestamp"));
    if (timestamp.isAfter(maxTimestamp)) {
        maxTimestamp = timestamp;
        index = i;
    }
}

if (index == -1) {
    return null;
}

return jsonArr.getJSONObject(index);
```

Comment: No need for the formatter object. The standard ISO 8601 format is parsed by default.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to use here. That class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

Comment: Agreed, about the ISO 8601 part. But can you share more about not using `LocalDateTime` here since we're comparing two timestamps, and don't actually care about the exact value. I know I can use `Instant` here much the same way and will refactor the code for that, but would like to know why is the current code discouraged, for the use case.

Comment: By using `LocalDateTime`, you are needlessly discarding valuable information (the offset) with **nothing gained** in return.

Comment: I have changed to Instant, to avoid any ambiguity. But for my own understanding, why's offset important in this particular case? In the end we're returning the entire `JSONObject` which has the timestamp as a `String`. The conversion is done only for comparison and doesn't affect the data being returned.

Comment: You might get away with it, but there is no benefit, no upside. Why go out of your way to discard information?

Comment: Of course I won't go out of my way to discard information, which is why I said I can do much the same thing using `Instant`. My question was around why it mattered for comparing two dates, which to begin with were not timezone sensitive. I wanted to understand what I was missing here, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

## `java.time.Instant`

Your timestamp strings are in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. These standard formats are used by default when the *java.time* classes are parsing/generating text.

Parse as `Instant` objects. Then sort.

```
List
.of(
    Instant.parse( "2022-12-14T10:03:30.343Z" ) , 
    Instant.parse( "2022-12-14T10:03:01.343Z" )
)
.stream()
.max( Instant :: compareTo )
.get()
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Ja2qnD).

> 2022-12-14T10:03:30.343Z

## Sort text

Or, if you just want the latest without really understanding the value as a date-time, just sort the text. ISO 8601 formats are cleverly designed to be in chronological order when sorted alphabetically.

Caveat: This approach assumes your inputs have the same number of digits in the fraction of a second. Seems like a risky assumption to me, so I would rather parse as an `Instant`.

```
List
.of(
    "2022-12-14T10:03:30.343Z" , 
    "2022-12-14T10:03:01.343Z"
)
.stream()
.max( String :: compareTo )
.get()
```

Comment: i tried your solution (code). but i get the error like this `java: invalid method reference   cannot find symbol     symbol:   method compare()    location: class java.time.Instant`.

Comment: @mmar Well, I did mean it more conceptually than literally, but… You can use [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#compareTo(java.time.Instant)), the method required by any class implementing [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). See [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Ja2qnD)